# How to code Ruby equivalent of PHP’s mcrypt_encrypt() function

Tags: ruby, encryption

If I write the following code

```
mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $raw, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);
```

How to write in ruby?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is Ruby equivalent using OpenSSL,

```
  cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher.new("aes-128-cbc")
  cipher.encrypt
  cipher.key = key
  cipher.iv = iv
  encrypted = cipher.update(raw)
  encrypted << cipher.final
```

Comment: Thank you for answering but bad decrypt (OpenSSL::Cipher::CipherError) occured What's wrong?

Comment: If your keysize is 32 bytes you need to write 'OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher.new("aes-256-cbc")'

Answer (score 1):

You can use the openssl library for this. I think what you need is here for symmetric key encryption:

http://stuff-things.net/2008/02/05/encrypting-lots-of-sensitive-data-with-ruby-on-rails/

Answer (score 0):

Can [ezcrypto](http://rubygems.org/gems/ezcrypto) help? Default it uses standard aes-128-cbc but does know other algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128 denotes the blocksize 16 Bytes and 3 key sizes are possible

1. $key ~ 16 Bytes (AES-128)

   `cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher.new("aes-128-cbc")`
2. $key ~ 24 Bytes (AES-192)

   `cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher.new("aes-192-cbc")`
3. $key ~ 32 Bytes (AES-256)

   `cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher.new("aes-256-cbc")`

And then we can use the following code to perform encryption

```
cipher.encrypt
cipher.key = key
cipher.iv = iv
encrypted = cipher.update(raw)
encrypted << cipher.final
```